# ¿Por qué me da error CS8602 y no me permite mostrar la información en MessageBox?

Tags: c#-8.0, messagebox

Antes que nada deciros que uso el entorno Visual Basic 2022 con .NET 8.
Es mi primera pregunta y espero hacerla lo más comprensible. Estoy siguiendo un curso de C# y en un ejercicio se plantea hacer una interfaz gráfica en WPF que contenga 2 filas: la fila superior tiene un ListBox dividido en 4 columnas que tiene a su vez TextBlock donde aparece el nombre de 2 ciudades con sus supuestas temperaturas medias. La fila inferior tiene un botón que, al clicarlo teniendo un elemento de la lista seleccionado, nos muestra un MessageBox con la información del elemento de la lista.
[image: Código en XAML]
(Ignorad el PreviewMouseDown).
Ahora, en C# creo una clase Poblaciones con 4 propiedades: Poblacion1, Poblacion2, Temperatura1 y Temperatura2:

[image: Clase Poblaciones]

Serán los objetos que cree al crear el List:

[image: List Poblaciones]

Pues bien, al crear en C# el List<> que asocio al ListBox obtiene la información, no tengo problema de que los datos se muestren en el ListBox, hasta ahí todo correcto, el problema viene al mostrar la información al darle al botón. Cuando desarrollo el evento, me dice que los elementos a mostrar devuleven "null". Si modificao para que solo muestre, por ejemplo, la temperatura, me dice que no se puede convertir el tipo int a string. En general, es como si obtener al la información del List no la adquisiera como se creó en la construcción de los objetos.
Este sería el evento:

[image: Evento botón]

Como veréis, aparece una advertencia en subrayado verde que dice: CS8602 : desreferencia de una referencia posiblemente nula. Y al probar la app, me da directamente un error:

[image: Error al pulsar el botón]
He buscado en internet, he leido la documentación, pero como tampoco soy un experto, no llego a comprender que es lo que pasa, más cuando sigo los pasos del video del curso y a él le sale perfectamente y a mi me genera esto.
Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! El codigo va como texto!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un `ListBox` permite seleccionar 1 o muchos elementos.

- `SelectedItem` sin la `s` final, para obtener el elemento seleccionado de la lista
- `SelectedItems` CON la `s` final, para selecciones multiples.

Cuando seleccionas un solo elemento puedes castearlo haciendo:

`listaPoblaciones.SelectedItem as Poblaciones`

Porque es un solo elemento

Pero cuando la selección es múltiple te dará error, ya que `listaPoblaciones.SelectedItems` (CON `s` final) no es **UN** elemento, si no que es una colección de elementos, especificamente es del tipo `System.Collection.IList` que no tiene conversión a `Poblaciones` y ahí tu error. Básicamente intentas convertir una lista en UN elemento

Comment: Diooooos, muchísimas gracias, solucionado. Típicos errores de novato. Mil Gracias.